# How to make a microcontroller to automatically learn human behavior detected by sensor

Tags: neural-network, microcontroller

I have a question of how to make microcontroller with sensor to learn the behaviour detected by sensor, and make control more intelligently. For example, an office with few people, has motion detection controlled light to save energy. When light switch turns on light, the light will be turned off automatically within 10 minutes if no motions is detected in last 10 minutes. 
Sometimes, people in office sit still without motion for more than 10 minutes, and light is turned off by timer. People has to wave hand to turn on the light, which is annoying. How to make a motion sensor to learn the people's behaviour, so that people does not need to wave hand very often in office hour?

If using neural network to solve the problem, how to model the input/output data? If not use NN, is there simple, better way to solve this problem?

Is such problem generic problem in other area?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest way would be to use some heuristics, like information about when working hours are, to improve system operation. You can try to use machine learning/NN to this, but this is a sort of (not so small) research project. There is a lot of approaches that can be used for that.

I would, probably, try to start from:

1. Collection of training samples. We need data samples where microcontroller turned light off correctly and not. (Thus we can train NN to classify situations into two classes "light should be turned off/not should be turned off", and that will be our output data). These can be probably found by the fact, if MC decision was overturned shortly, or not (providing you have data from sensor and MC decisions recorder somewhere. If not, you will need to start recording, and wait until data will be collected).
2. Extract some input features. Examples are time of the day (maybe binary "working hours/not working hours", sensor activation pattern for some timeframe before motion stopped etc. A number of ways exist to encode such time dependent patterns (see for example [this question and answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137721/neural-network-classification-from-time-series/137765#137765) at Cross Validated). These data will be your inputs
3. Train model. Maybe start from simple models like logistic regression, since your model will need to run on MC, and also it will be hard to collect lot of training samples.
4. Test your system on data, that was not included in training set. If results are good, port prediction code to MC, otherwise return to step 1-3

As you see, this can be long, time-consuming endevour, without 100% guarantee of success.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do such research (no MC), and to come up with training data similar to you mentioned. It is still in progress. If I could achieve the goal, NN is extremely simple. Now the question is there other way to achieve this with less or similar effort (I had big assumption I could achieve this now)? I am trying to validate if the effort is worth my time, as I am not expert in this field. If you have similar problem, would you think NN or other method which might be very obvious able to do this.

Comment: For training data output, the prediction is obtained by observing past. I am not familiar with TDNN, but I will study it.

Comment: @user3792705 How about putting some sensor on the door, so microcontroller could count how many people left the room? This is at least guaranteed to work. It is not obvious if NN (or other ML method) can work here, because I'm not sure if sensor activation pattern have some meaningful relationship with the fact that all people  left the room (can you distinguish these situations by looking at the data plots?). Another point is how many samples you can realistically obtain.

Comment: Counting people could make MC code and circuit complicated, and some room could have 2 doors. I am search solution with simple motion sensor circuit + (possible ML or other method). And it has to be independent without wire or wireless connections.

Comment: I agree motion count is not that meaningful, but may be it does not matter how many people in the room. I feel how to measure light-false-off is more important. Because ML will need to learn that. The sample data has to be obtained in real-time of real office. Pretrained NN may make the smart sensor not very effective.

Comment: @user3792705 Running any machine learning algorithm in microcontroller is much more complicated code than counting people, and also potentially very resource consuming - means you will need support for fast floating point arithmetics  and sufficient memory at least. Pretrained NN and offline expirements are needed here as proof-of-principle because you need to demonstrate that solution is possible. Once you have enough data collected, you can run quick expirements to see what really works and how much resources it consume.

Comment: Thus, a preferable strategy here, is probably to somehow collect and record real dataset, develop algorithm that runs on desktop computer, and only then port it to microcontroller

Comment: I appreciate your input, and I will try it.